# Storing columns that are added/removed frequently

Tags: php, mysql, rdbms

I have two ideas for storing user's customizations/settings for my web app. There are probably more ways of doing this, and I'm open to new ideas.

Which method would you recommend for storing settings/customizations that might change erratically? For instance, this week have 12 possible customizations a user can make. Next week we may add a new one with short notice.

So, I could:

1. Store the settings as columns (`user_image_url` as varchar, `time_offset` as int, `background_color` as varchar, etc.) with the user account as the primary key. I don't like the idea of having to add another column whenever there is a new setting (and having potentially dozens of columns), but I think this is the easiest, fastest, and most apparent way.
2. Make a table that stores only account ID, setting ID, and setting value as a varchar. So, something like `(account_id, setting_id, value) values (1, 2, 'http://logos.com/yourlogo.png')`. The idea would be to join it with a `settings` table that stores the `setting_id`. The big downside to this (that I can see) is that every setting would have to be the same type (varchar). I'm not sure if that will bite me in the butt later.

Thanks!

Comment: It largely depends on how often they're added or removed; adding and removing columns may take a while if the table is sufficiently large. The second option is also called EAV modelling.

Comment: yes, i have been at companies where it is hard to add columns and you gotta set up a second database and do the switcheroo. thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "sparse" values that are dynamic, your second version is a viable method of storing the values.  This is called an entity-attribute-value model (EAV).  I find that it works well (enough) in a hybrid arrangement.  That is, one record per user with lots of common information shared by all or most users.  Then a separate table with special settings.

There are a lot of issues with EAV models.  Performance can be an issue with large data sets.  The size of the table is much larger, because the entity id and attribute name (or id) are repeated across many rows.  However, some important systems such as Wordpress use this approach.

One big advantage is that you can have more than the 4,096 attributes -- and 4,096 is the maximum number of columns for MySQL.  I doubt you will have that many settings, but it is nice to know that you can get around this limit if necessary (and the limit is lower in many other databases).

Finally, you can fix the type problem by having multiple columns -- typically a `varchar`, a `float` (of some sort), and a `datetime` -- along with a type column.  That way, you can directly store values.  If you do go the `varchar` route, be sure you store dates in the ISO format of YYYY-MM-DD (you can omit the hyphens if you prefer).

Comment: i did not think of adding different columns for different data types! this is a great idea and might solve my specific problem 100%. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 violates the First Normal Form of relational database design.  Option 2 is the best way to go. There are many available explanations of First Normal Form available on the Web -- this is the simplest I've found:  http://www.andrewrollins.com/2009/08/11/database-normalization-first-second-and-third-normal-forms/